# How to reduce the margin between two rows/containers in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows in two containers, but I can't figure out how to reduce  the bottom and top margin/padding to bring the content closer.

The `bottom content` is way too far and I would like to bring it closer to the first row/container.
I tried to apply padding and margin to the rows and containers with no luck.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pbPd/) of the html below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul id="top-nav" class="nav">
                    <li data-current-nav="Home"><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                bottom content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `margin-bottom` on `ul#top-nav`:

```
#top-nav {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

See the updated jsFiddle for a demonstration > http://jsfiddle.net/6pbPd/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the bottom margin of `ul.nav` (20px) and the rule applied to the `min-height` of the container `div` (30px):

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
   min-height: 20px;
}

#top-nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6pbPd/4/

Comment: Why 20 ? And **why** `!important` ? Don't get fooled by jsfiddle structure : [http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/6pbPd/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/6pbPd/3/). Good answer anyway I think.

Comment: the style applied to row-fluid has some side effect on other places, but margin-bottom works great.

Comment: Totally fooled by jsFiddle structure O_o Thanks @Sherbrow, could you elaborate more ? I'm very interested...

Comment: You have to use the sidebar to include resources, for the right css panel to be included after your resources - just a matter of order really, jsfiddle don't need the <head> nor the <body> in the html panel. See [jsFiddle Hacks](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack).